# Nginx Basic Auth and subfolders

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, basic-authentication, password-protection

I have a problem with subfolders in a basic auth procted folder. In the protected folder i have a folder named phpmyadmin, which contains phpmyadmin. Im not able to run phpmyadmin, when basic is activated. Whenn i call the the folder, i get a save-as dialog (type: application/octet-stream (18,3 KB)).

Here the important parts of mysites-available/default

```
location ^~ /administration/ {
    auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/myproject/sec/htpasswd;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Any ideas, how i can run php in basic-auth protected subfolders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just repeat the `location ~ \.php$` block inside the `/administration/` block.

As a workaround, I've also used this setup with success, which saves me from repeating the PHP configuration over and over in complex scenarios.

```
location ^~ /administration/ {
    auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/myproject/sec/htpasswd;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files /dummy/$uri @php;
   }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files /dummy/$uri @php;
}

location @php {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

It basically uses a [named location](http://wiki.nginx.org/Faq#What.27s_this_.40_thing_mean.3F) for the PHP configuration. Unfortunately you can not use such a location everywhere. But it works with [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files). You should make sure, that there's no directory `/dummy/` on your server.